Why is using multiple CUDA streams not improving performance as expected?
I am working on optimizing a CUDA application that processes a matrix by updating each row sequentially. The process involves three main kernels:
Kernel 1: Updates the pivot element of the current row.
Kernel 2: Performs updates on the row immediately following the pivot.
Kernel 3: Updates all subsequent rows based on the current pivot row.
Initially, I used a 2-stream approach which, while functional, resulted in significant wait times for the first stream, as it had to wait for the second stream to complete a large chunk of the matrix update.
Initial 2 Stream Approach:
cudaStream_t stream1, stream2;
cudaEvent_t event1, event2;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            kernel1<<<1, 512, 0, stream1>>>(i, dynamic_parameters);
            kernel2<<<1, 512, 0, stream2>>>(i, dynamic_parameters);
            kernel3<<<1, 512, 0, stream1>>>(i, dynamic_parameters);
            cudaEventRecord(event1, stream2);
            cudaEventRecord(event2, stream1);
        } else {
            cudaStreamWaitEvent(stream1, event1, 0);
            kernel1<<<1, 512, 0, stream1>>>(i, dynamic_parameters);
            cudaStreamWaitEvent(stream2, event2, 0);
            kernel2<<<1, 512, 0, stream2>>>(i, dynamic_parameters);
            cudaEventRecord(event1, stream2);
            kernel3<<<1, 512, 0, stream1>>>(i, dynamic_parameters);
            cudaEventRecord(event2, stream1);
        }
    }

Trace of 2 streams approach in Nsight Systems:

In the trace, it is evident that kernels 1 and 2 in the first stream experience significant waiting times. This is due to the more extensive workload present in stream 2.e
New 5 stream Approach :
const int numStreams = 5; // Using 5 streams
cudaStream_t streams[numStreams];
cudaEvent_t updateEvents[numStreams]; // One event for each stream

// Gradual increase in workload

for (int i= 0; i< 1024; i++) 
{
    if(i== 0)
    {
            kernel1<<<1, 512, 0, streams[0]>>>(i,*/params*/);
            kernel2<<<1, 512, 0, streams[0]>>>(i+1,*/params*/);
            cudaEventRecord(updateEvents[0], streams[0]);
            

            // Stream 2: Update matrix rows 3 to 10
            if (i+ 2 <= 1024) 
            {
                int endRow = min(i+ 10 , 1024);
                dim3 gridDim(1, ((endRow -(i+1)+ 1) + 128- 1) /128);
         kernel3<<<gridDim, blockDim, 0, streams[1]>>>(*/params*/, i+2(start Row) , (endRow));
                cudaEventRecord(updateEvents[1], streams[1]);
            }

            // Stream 3: Update matrix rows 11 to 100
            if (i+ 11 <= m) 
            {
                
                int endRow = min(i+ 100, 1024);
               dim3 gridDim(1, ((endRow - (i+11) + 1) +128- 1)/128);
               kernel3<<<gridDim, blockDim, 0, streams[2]>>>(*/params*/, i+11(start Row) , (endRow));
                cudaEventRecord(updateEvents[2], streams[2]);
            }

            // Stream 4: Update matrix rows 101 to 500
            if (i+ 101 <= 1024) 
            {
                int endRow = min(i+ 500, 1024);
                dim3 gridDim(1, ((endRow - (i+ 101 ) + 1 ) + 128- 1) / ROW_PER_BLOCK);
           kernel3<<<gridDim, blockDim, 0, streams[2]>>>(*/params*/, i+101(start Row),(endRow));
                cudaEventRecord(updateEvents[3], streams[3]);
            }

            // Stream 5: Update matrix rows 501 to 1024
            if (i+ 501 <= 1024) {
            dim3 gridDim(1, ((1024 - (i+501) + 1) + 128 - 1)/ 128);
           kernel3<<<gridDim, blockDim, 0, streams[4]>>>(*/params*/, i+501(start Row),1024);
                cudaEventRecord(updateEvents[4], streams[4]);
            }
    }

    else
    {   
        if(i+1<=1024)
        {
            cudaStreamWaitEvent(streams[0],updateEvents[1]);
            kernel1<<<1, 512, 0, streams[0]>>>(i,*/params*/);
            kernel2<<<1, 512, 0, streams[0]>>>(i+1,*/params*/);
            cudaEventRecord(updateEvents[0], streams[0]);
        }

        // Stream 2: Update matrix rows 3 to 10
        if (i+ 2 <= 1024) {
            cudaStreamWaitEvent(streams[1], updateEvents[2], 0);
            cudaStreamWaitEvent(streams[1], updateEvents[0], 0);
            int endRow = min(i+ 10 , 1024);
            dim3 gridDim(1, ((endRow -(i+1)+ 1) + 128- 1) /128);
 kernel3<<<gridDim, blockDim, 0, streams[1]>>>(*/params*/, i+2(start Row) , (endRow));
                cudaEventRecord(updateEvents[1], streams[1]);
        }
         else {
            dummyKernel<<<1, 1, 0, streams[1]>>>();
            cudaEventRecord(updateEvents[1], streams[1]); // Ensure the event is always recorded
        }

        // Stream 3: Update matrix rows 11 to 100
        if (i+ 11 <= 1024) {
           cudaStreamWaitEvent(streams[2], updateEvents[3], 0); // Wait for stream 4
           cudaStreamWaitEvent(streams[2], updateEvents[0], 0); // Wait for pivot update
            int endRow = min(i+ 100, 1024);
               dim3 gridDim(1, ((endRow - (i+11) + 1) +128- 1)/128);
               kernel3<<<gridDim, blockDim, 0, streams[2]>>>(*/params*/, i+11(start Row) , (endRow));
                cudaEventRecord(updateEvents[2], streams[2]);
        }
        else {
            dummyKernel<<<1, 1, 0, streams[2]>>>();
            cudaEventRecord(updateEvents[2], streams[2]); // Ensure the event is always recorded
        }       

        // Stream 4: Update matrix rows 101 to 500
        if (i+ 101 <= 1024) {
            cudaStreamWaitEvent(streams[3], updateEvents[4], 0); // Wait for stream 5
            cudaStreamWaitEvent(streams[3], updateEvents[0], 0); // Wait for pivot update
            int endRow = min(i+ 500, 1024);
                dim3 gridDim(1, ((endRow - (i+ 101 ) + 1 ) + 128- 1) / ROW_PER_BLOCK);
           kernel3<<<gridDim, blockDim, 0, streams[2]>>>(*/params*/, i+101(start Row),(endRow));
                cudaEventRecord(updateEvents[3], streams[3]);
        }
        else {
            dummyKernel<<<1, 1, 0, streams[3]>>>();
            cudaEventRecord(updateEvents[3], streams[3]); // Ensure the event is always recorded
        }
        // Stream 5: Update matrix rows 501 to m
        if (i+ 501 <= 1024) {
            cudaStreamWaitEvent(streams[4], updateEvents[0], 0);
           dim3 gridDim(1, ((1024 - (i+501) + 1) + 128 - 1)/ 128);
           kernel3<<<gridDim, blockDim, 0, streams[4]>>>(*/params*/, i+501(start Row),1024);
                cudaEventRecord(updateEvents[4], streams[4]);
        }
        else {
            dummyKernel<<<1, 1, 0, streams[4]>>>();
            cudaEventRecord(updateEvents[4], streams[4]); // Ensure the event is always recorded
        }
    }
        
}

Trace of 5 streams approach in the Nsight Systems:

Despite the logical distribution of workload, the 5-stream approach is running slower than the original 2-stream setup. I suspect this may be due to overhead from managing multiple streams, kernel launch latencies, or perhaps inefficient synchronization.
Why might using multiple CUDA streams (increasing from 2 to 5) be less efficient in this scenario? How can I effectively balance the workload among streams to improve performance?
Are there best practices for stream synchronization in scenarios with dependent operations like this?

Have you looked at the execution with Nvidia Nsight Systems? It's usually pretty good at revealing issues like these and might give us a hint about how to find and fix it

Your streams all depend on each other through updateEvents so they do not increase the amount of concurrent work while adding complexity. Not sure what you are trying to achieve here. Maybe it would help if you would include the faster 2-stream code as well.

What sort of problem are you trying to solve? A variant of Gaussian elimination perhaps? Tell us more about your approach.

@JanezKuhar I am trying to solve QR factorization using householder algorithm

Just to make sure: You know that CuSolver contains a QR factorization, right?

@Homer512 Yes, while CuSolver provides QR factorization, it does not meet the specific requirements of my application. I need access to the intermediate results of each processed row, which CuSolver does not provide

The light blue row in the profiler labelled kernel is the total occupancy, right? It looks like it is at 100% all the time except for that tiny gap between two kernels. The added complexity may not be worth it just to fill that gap. It's possible that secondary effects such as reduced cache efficiency take over in the complex scheme. But that's just a guess.

@Homer512 Indeed, in both approaches, the occupancy is 100%. However, in the second approach, the wait time for kernels 1 and 2 is reduced, which was my objective. While later rows may still experience long wait times, the initial rows no longer need to wait as long. In the two-stream approach, the initial rows had to wait for a considerable time. To decrease this wait time, I chose a five-stream approach, which gradually divides the workload and thus reduces the wait time.

I'm … slightly confused. Do you mean that the five-stream should result in better cache usage? Because otherwise it sounds like you agree with me that performance gains should not be possible (since occupancy was already good) and since there is no such thing as a free lunch, every added complexity can only decrease overall performance. Right?

@Homer512 You make a valid point about the "no free lunch" principle. Regarding cache usage, my intention was to ensure that smaller, more frequent tasks keep relevant data in cache longer. As I explained, my kernels update a row adjacent to the pivot row in the next iteration, which previously required waiting for the kernel execution in the other stream to complete. To decrease this wait time, I decided to split the workload across multiple streams
